# Invalid field name in struct literal Golang

Tags: go, struct

I have this struct  call Status and have inside another struct call Data

```
package model

import "time"

type Status struct {
    Data struct {
        OrderId                   string    json:"orderId"
        DisputeStatus             string    json:"disputeStatus"
        DisputeCauseCategoryName  string    json:"disputeCauseCategoryName"
        ReverseLogisticCost         string        json:"ReverseLogisticCost"
        
    } json:"data"
    StatusJ string json:"status" 
}
```

And i have this function

```
func (s StatusServices) UpdateStatusItem(ctx context.Context, status model.Status) (error) {

        statusDetails := model.Status{
            
                OrderID: status.Data.OrderID,
        }

}
```

In OrderId appear the error Invalid field name, i tried with this

```
statusDetails := model.Status{
            Data: status.Data{
                OrderID: status.Data.OrderID,
            },
        }
```

but i doesn't work, what can i do

Comment: `OrderId` is not `OrderID`, Go's identifiers are very much case sensitive.

Comment: I change and and still the same error

Comment: `model.Status{ OrderID: ...` is invalid because `model.Status` has no field `OrderID`. And `model.Status{Data: status.Data{` is invalid because you haven't defined a `status.Data` type.

Comment: When initializing a nested field in a composite literal you have to specify the parent field's type, i.e. to initialize `OrderID` you have to specify the type of `Data`, and since that field's type is *anonymous* you have to specify the full definition: https://play.golang.org/p/53lDRKHrj5i

Comment: You can avoid this by initializing the nested field outside of the composite literal with plain field assignment: https://play.golang.org/p/Y29P_TVbtbl

Comment: Or you can avoid this by not using anonymous structs and properly declaring the field's type upfront: https://play.golang.org/p/hsP8IrE042J

Comment: Your code is missing backticks around the `json:...` struct tags. Are they missing in your original code, or did they get lost when you copied your code to stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2):

The type `model.Status` has a field `Data` with a type defined as

```
struct {
    OrderId                   string    json:"orderId"
    DisputeStatus             string    json:"disputeStatus"
    DisputeCauseCategoryName  string    json:"disputeCauseCategoryName"
    ReverseLogisticCost       string    json:"ReverseLogisticCost"       
}
```

To initialize the variable, you can use a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), more specifically a `struct literal`

```golang
func main() {
    s := Status{
        Data: struct {
            OrderId                  string `json:"orderId"`
            DisputeStatus            string `json:"disputeStatus"`
            DisputeCauseCategoryName string `json:"disputeCauseCategoryName"`
            ReverseLogisticCost      string `json:"ReverseLogisticCost"`
        }{OrderId: "123456"},
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/nLhLHNNf7Jb

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can initialize a struct with a nested struct this way.

Best is to give the nested struct its own type. OR you can start with an empty struct (eg var m model.Status) and then (in a separate line) assign to s.Data.OrderId.

I believe you can only assign to a nested struct if you define and initialize it in one go (as is often done in go tests) which is consistent with the idea that this construct is useful only for onetime off uses.

Comment: Bear in mind: you can initialize the way that OP thinks that they can. Just that the syntax looks incredibly ugly.

Comment: The reason why I say that it looks ugly, is because you'd effectively be copying+pasting the entire struct definition. This is an example: https://play.golang.org/p/xNginb0oJKD.

Comment: You might argue "that's such a stupid way of doing it". But I feel that I should mention it, because it's important to understand the syntax and semantics of Go.

Comment: thanks, that is what I meant by "you can only assign to a nested struct if you define and initialize it in one go".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it answers your question, but you may want to modify your model a little bit from :

```
type Status struct {
    Data struct {
        OrderId                   string    json:"orderId"
        DisputeStatus             string    json:"disputeStatus"
        DisputeCauseCategoryName  string    json:"disputeCauseCategoryName"
        ReverseLogisticCost         string        json:"ReverseLogisticCost"
        
    } json:"data"
    StatusJ string json:"status" 
}
```

To:

```
type Status struct {
    Data      Data      `json:"data"`
    StatusJ   string    `json:"status"`
}

type Data struct {
    OrderID                   string    `json:"orderId"`
    DisputeStatus             string    `json:"disputeStatus"`
    DisputeCauseCategoryName  string    `json:"disputeCauseCategoryName"`
    ReverseLogisticCost       string    `json:"reverseLogisticCost"`
}
```

- Check the capital letter; in your example you had `OrderId` in your `Data` struct but `status.Data.OrderID` in your function.
- Also your field Status does not contain an `OrderID` field which you were setting in your function.
- As mentionned in comment, backticks were missing around your json tags.

A proper IDE would catch those.

Answer (score 0):

Change `OrderID` to `OrderId`,declare the field's type upfront as per suggestion of mkopriva:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type StatusData struct {
    OrderId                  string `json:"orderId"`
    DisputeStatus            string `json:"disputeStatus"`
    DisputeCauseCategoryName string `json:"disputeCauseCategoryName"`
    ReverseLogisticCost      string `json:"ReverseLogisticCost"`
}

type Status struct {
    Data    StatusData
    StatusJ string
}

func main() {
    s := Status{Data: StatusData{OrderId: "123456"}}
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
{{123456   } }
```